# Having my newly added interstitial(admob) shown when the player dies

Tags: swift, admob, ads

I've added some interstitial ads into my game. As of right now, I have the ad connected to a button in the center of the screen. What I would like to do is to have the ad automatically shown whenever the player dies. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is my code for the interstitial ads:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import GoogleMobileAds

//I added this
protocol GameInterstitialDelegate {
func openInterstitial()
}


class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate, 
GADInterstitialDelegate {

var fullScreenAds :GADInterstitial!

//I added this
extension GameViewController: GameInterstitialDelegate {
    func openInterstitial() {
        self.fullScreenAds = CreateAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
}

func CreateAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial? {
    fullScreenAds = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-
6532333990655924/8291640688")
    guard let fullScreenAds = fullScreenAds else {
        return nil
    }

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    fullScreenAds.load(request)
    fullScreenAds.delegate = self

    return fullScreenAds

}

func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    print("ads loaded")
    ad.present(fromRootViewController: self)
}

func interstitialDidFail(toPresentScreen ad: GADInterstitial) {
    print("ad did not load")
}
}
```

This is my playerDied function:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

//I added this
weak var interstitialDelegate: GameInterstitialDelegate?

//I added this
var gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
gameScene.interstitialDelegate = self

func playedDied() {

    self.removeAction(forKey: "SpawnCar2")
    self.removeAction(forKey: "SpawnCar3")
    self.removeAction(forKey: "SpawnCoin")

    for child in children {

        if child.name == "Car2" {
            child.removeAction(forKey: "MoveCar2")
        } else if child.name == "Car3" {
            child.removeAction(forKey: "MoveCar3")
        } else if child.name == "Coin" {
            child.removeAction(forKey: "MoveCoin")
        }

    }

    isAlive = false

    let highscore = GameManager.instance.getHighscore()

    if highscore < score {
        GameManager.instance.setHighscore(highscore: score)
    }

    let retry = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Retry")
    let quit = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Quit")

    retry.name = "Retry"
    retry.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    retry.position = CGPoint(x: -150, y: -150)
    retry.zPosition = 7
    retry.setScale(0)

    quit.name = "Quit"
    quit.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    quit.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: -150)
    quit.zPosition = 7
    quit.setScale(0)

    let scaleUp = SKAction.scale(to: 0.8, duration: TimeInterval(0.5))

    retry.run(scaleUp)
    quit.run(scaleUp)

    self.addChild(retry)
    self.addChild(quit)

    //I added this
    interstitialDelegate?.openInterstitial()
}
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if atPoint(location).name == "Play" {
            gameplay!.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(gameplay!, transition: 
            SKTransition.fade(withDuration: TimeInterval(1)))
        }

        if atPoint(location).name == "Highscore" {
            scoreLabel.removeFromParent()
            createLabel()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I've searched a bit more on `SpriteKit` and it seems the easy way to do what you want to do is with notifications.

`UIViewController:`

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate, 
GADInterstitialDelegate {
    // rest of the controller code

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(openInterstitial), name: "playerDied", object: nil)
    }

    func openInterstitial() {
        self.fullScreenAds = CreateAndLoadInterstitial()
    }

    // rest of the controller code
}
```

`SKScene:`

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    func playedDied() {
        // rest of the method code

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "playerDied",
                                    object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my text above. Although I now have 3 errors. I probably put some of the things in the wrong place.

Comment: The extension should be outside de scope of your GameViewController class not inside. Edited my answer.

Comment: Oh, that fixed the error. One more issue, where should I put the code "var gameScene = GameScene(...)" and "gameScene.interstitialDelegate = self"?

Comment: Where do you init your `GameScene` class? Is it in your `GameViewController` class? If so, you need to set the `interstitialDelegate` there. the `4)` point in my answer was an example.

Comment: What do you mean with "where do you init your GameScene class?"

Comment: could you add to your post the code where you create your GameScene and add it to the view? (sorry I'm not very good with explanations)

Comment: Well, I have a MainMenuScene that is the starting screen. There I have a "Play" button that takes me to the "GameplayScene" I added that code in the screen above.

Comment: Ok my method was not good for SpriteKit applications. I've completely edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy!! Absolute legend! You'll get an upvote!!